# Modx выборка из бд с условием

Tags: php, modx

Сейчас работаю с CMF ModX и возникла задача вывести данные в два списка.То-есть одну половину данных в один список, а вторую во второй. Участник сообщества Tunker, предложил данное решение:

```
[[!getImageList?
&tvname=`faq`
&toJsonPlaceholder=`jsonoutfaq`
&tpl=``
&totalVar=`totalfaq`
]]
[[!getImageList?
&value=`[[+jsonoutfaq]]`
&limit=[[+totalfaq:div=`2`]]
&tpl=`faqTemplate`
]]
[[!getImageList?
&value=`[[+jsonoutfaq]]`
&offset=[[+totalimg:gt=`1`:then=`[[+totalimg:div=`2`]]`:else=`1`]]
&tpl=`faqTemplate`
]]
```

В первом вызове считаем к-ство элементов, во втором указываем ограничение и выводим первую половину. А в третьем пропускаем половину элементов и выводим оставшуюся часть. Но у меня, код работает не так как нужно, при нечетности к-ства элементов. Если их будет 5, то выведется 6 элементов, то-есть средний, третий элемент выведется 2 раза. Подскажите, почему так происходит и как это исправить.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить версию migx до последней, у вас совсем старая

Comment: @Tunker Я ошибся. Подумал что вы о версии modx, а migx у меня 2.9.6-pl, так что проблема не в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже отвечал у меня при проверке работает все нормально, может версия php или еще что. Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
[[!getImageList?
&value=`[[+jsonoutfaq]]`
&offset=[[+totalimg:mod=`2`:eq=`0`:then=`[[+totalimg:div=`2`]]`:else=`[[+totalimg:div=`2`:add=`1`]]`]]
&tpl=`faqTemplate`
]]
```

У меня он работает некорректно, нечетные записи пропускается 1, но логика запроса такая:
если остаток от деления на 2 равен 0 (т.е. кол-во записей четное) то выводим как обычно, если 1 (т.е. кол-во записей нечетное) то увеличиваем смещение на 1

Comment: Это работает отлично, большое вам спасибо!)